# Code highlighting no longer displaying

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Today, when I've been visiting the various SE sites (especially SO), the code syntax highlighting hasn't been kicking in. Instead, this is what I see:

[image: Code block without syntax highlighting]

I've restarted my computer, restarted Chrome, cleared the cache (and restarted Chrome again afterwards), but I still can't get the syntax highlighting to kick back in again. However, it seems to work fine on Opera, Firefox, and Safari. What's going on?

**EDIT:** Even after turning off my Adblocker, I'm still getting some errors.
[image: Externally loaded JS not loading]

Which, when paired with the Webkit's Developer Console, returns this error message:
[image: Chrome not running JavaScript script]

(There is no accompanying message regarding line number, but I believe this is the error, as the script linked on the following line fails since jQuery was not loaded.) Refreshing and restarting (both Chrome and my computer) didn't change anything, so what's the issue? I haven't installed any software updates for a while, so unless Chrome silently downloaded an update that's been breaking SO's scripts, I don't think that's the problem.

I should also add that this is the first time seeing this "External JavaScript" message, so I don't think it's the Adblocker plugin anymore.

Comment: If you check the message log in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+J) when some unhighlighted code is displayed, do you see anything unusual? Also: do you have any extensions installed that might interfere?

Comment: @Shog9 I only get the "Failed to load resource" message from the ad servers/CDN in the console. As for extensions, I have the SE keyboard shortcuts, TT+, Adblocker, Turn off the Lights, and some other Turntable related extensions, so I don't think those are blocking it.

Comment: It's not just the ads that are pulled from the CDN... Try opening an Incognito-mode Chrome window and loading a page with some code on it, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is back in Incognito. There are no errors; just warnings that the `Content-type` header may be incorrect for some of the responses.

Comment: Try disabling your adblocker first then - there's a reasonable chance it's tripping up the highlighter script. If that doesn't work, just disable the rest, verify it works, and finally start *enabling* them one by one until it breaks again.

Comment: @Shog9 It was Adblocker. Odd though, since this is the first time it's broken SO, and I've been using it for months.

Comment: @Edwin: You should post an answer if you've found the solution. Other people might have the same problem with Adblocker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with Adblocker. If you have adblocking services, be sure to whitelist `stackoverflow.com/questions`.